# Can we keep a dead person's image as phone wallpaper?

Tags: quran, muslim-practices

My mother passed away 8 years back.

Since then I have kept my mother's photo as a wallpaper on my phone. My family members are asking me to remove it from wallpaper and store it in photo album only.

But I like to see my mother's face again n again...thats why I have kept her photo... Is there any problem in keeping photos on mobile screen?

Comment: This should be a two part question - Is it ok to take photographs in Islam & If yes, can I keep the photograph of my mother as my mobile wallpaper.

Comment: I doubt that there is any evident prohibition against it, especially considering their suggestion, what difference does it make if it is in your album or wallpaper?

Answer (score -1):

here is sum points

1. taking picture in Islam is prohibited
2. setting picture of a woman on wallpaper is not good (i can be seen by a non mahram)

[Ref of point 1](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/365/ruling-on-photographs)

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your claims?

Comment: on which point ? 1st or 2nd !

Comment: Of course for both.

Comment: for point 1) https://islamqa.info/en/answers/365/ruling-on-photographs

Comment: that belongs to your post not in comments.